# "Situation management" in LaTeX / expl3?

Tags: macros, conditionals, expl3, programming, branching

It happens from time to time that I would like to implement LaTeX commands that behave differently depending on the situation.

E.g., a command that returns different compositions of tokens depending on the situation, like:

*⟨tokens in case LaTeX processes normal text⟩*
*⟨tokens in case LaTeX processes stuff that goes into a \newlabel-entry in the .aux-file⟩*
*⟨tokens in case LaTeX processes stuff that goes into a \@writefile-entry in the .aux-file⟩*
*⟨tokens in case LaTeX processes stuff that goes into page-headings⟩*
*⟨tokens in case LaTeX spits out a \nameref-reference⟩*
*⟨tokens in case LaTeX writes to screen⟩*
*⟨tokens in case LaTeX writes to file⟩*
*⟨tokens in case LaTeX processes a pdf-string⟩*

Just recently I started a discussion here in TeX-LaTeX-StackExchange about how to find out if TeX is currently evaluating a component of a `\pgfmathparse`-expression (as provided by TikZ/pgf/pgfmath), but which is not nested in the `\pgfmathparse` quote operator:

*⟨tokens in case LaTeX evaluates a component of a \pgfmathparse-expression outside quotes⟩*

Again and again it happens that I would like to fork out according to certain situations.
It would also be imaginable, for example:

*⟨tokens in case LaTeX is evaluating \MakeLowercase⟩*
*⟨tokens in case LaTeX is evaluating \MakeUppercase⟩*

Or perhaps fork according to whether the command is called within a particular environment:

*⟨tokens in case LaTeX is processing an instance of the environment foobar⟩*

Or perhaps fork according to whether the command appears within some argument of a certain other macro:

*⟨tokens in case LaTeX is processing the 3rd argument of macro \foobar⟩*

At the moment LaTeX programmers often have no choice but to think of more or less complicated ways to determine if LaTeX is in a particular situation.

My question is:

Are there packages/projects that provide a kind of "situation management"?
E.g. in the form of flags that are set automatically when certain situations are triggered and that can be checked?
Preferably a kind of "situation management" in such a way that
a) the thing is extensible if someone writes their own package with their own situation types  and
b) when new situation-types are introduced more forks/branches can be added to already-defined macros where forking depending on situation-types/situation-flags takes place?
Is something like that intended for expl3?

Comment: This is just a side remark concerning your `\pgfmathparse` example: it does actually even more checks, such as `\ifpgfmathunitsdeclared` to see if the argument is a "scalar" or has units. (Please do not ask me why the unit-less object is referred to as a "scalar".) Also `\pgfkeys{/tikz/.unknown/.code=% ...` in `tikz.code.tex` is worth a read if you want to actually know how Ti*k*Z makes sense of `\draw[red] ...` (as opposed to `\draw[color=red] ...`. So this is also to point you to the `.unknown` key handler.

Comment: @TikZling The first sentence of [the German-language-entry for the word Skalar](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skalar_(Mathematik)) (=scalar in english) says: "A scalar is a mathematical quantity which is characterised **solely by the specification of a single numerical value** (in physics possibly with unit)." So the term scalar probably was chosen because `\pgfmath` is more about math (not so much about physics) and "scalars" in math are about specifying single numerical values without units. Another question: Why is a thing that is to be specified by several components called `\coordinate`?

Comment: I think that the notion "coordinate" makes sense. A scalar is something that transforms trivially under coordinate transformations. Not something that does not have units.

Comment: @TikZling Afaik a coordinate (singular) is a *single* value. In TikZ the thing which is called `\coordinate` is to be specified by *several* values, therefore - imho - calling it  `\coordinates` (plural) might make more sense.

Comment: Nope, not generally. For instance, if you have a point in the complex plane, would you call `z` its coordinates (since clearly the real dimension of the complex plane is 2)? Of course, I agree that the notion "coordinate" isn't really good, maybe "point" would be better, but "coordinate" is not totally off. However, this is different from referring to a dimensionless as "scalar", this does not make any sense because in this context a dimensionless component of a vector would become a scalar....

Comment: @TikZling Ad "scalar": To make it clear: I do agree with you. And I do not defend this "scalar"-terminology of TikZ. I have merely tried to find an explanation of how it might have come about. ;-) I think it is misleading. To my knowledge (it is a long time since I had to learn such mathematics - maybe I don't recall correctly) a scalar is an element of a field underlying a vector space. As the elements of any field may be used as the scalars for a vector space, the term "scalar" actually does not just refer to (whatsoever) "numbers without units".

Comment: This is a very interesting question. I have been studying source code of `web2c` because I think there is a large room for improvement for the current TeX implementation. Programming in LaTeX is still difficult: the syntax of `expl3` is hideous; Lua is a simplistic script language that is not very development-efficient. The design of LuaTeX still does not provide enough **exposure** for the lower-level TeX parsing mechanism: the nodes are formed after parsing, but TeX parsing is a black box. It would be nice if a TeX implementation opens up even more detail of the parser.